# Java Gif on Label Background Squares Showing?

Tags: java, swing, gif

I am trying to use .gif on my app, and its not going good.. when I add the .gif it shows the label with my .gif moving.. but there are squares beside it :s
Kinda akward...

This is my .gif:
http://sadpanda.us/images/872436-4CD65DA.gif

And here is my code:

```
public class TestGif {

    private JFrame frame;


    public TestGif(){
        this.frame = new JFrame("teste");
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("dark.gif");
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        icon.setImageObserver(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new TestGif();
    }
}
```

Thanks alot in advance, sorry my bad english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using solution from Riven at http://riven8192.blogspot.com/2010/02/image-java-animated-gifs.html

**ImageUtil.java:**

```
public class ImageUtil
{
    public static BufferedImage convertRGBAToGIF(BufferedImage src, int transColor)
    {
        BufferedImage dst = new BufferedImage(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);
        Graphics g = dst.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(new Color(transColor));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, dst.getWidth(), dst.getHeight());
        {
            IndexColorModel indexedModel = (IndexColorModel) dst.getColorModel();
            WritableRaster raster = dst.getRaster();
            int sample = raster.getSample(0, 0, 0);
            int size = indexedModel.getMapSize();
            byte[] rr = new byte[size];
            byte[] gg = new byte[size];
            byte[] bb = new byte[size];
            indexedModel.getReds(rr);
            indexedModel.getGreens(gg);
            indexedModel.getBlues(bb);
            IndexColorModel newModel = new IndexColorModel(8, size, rr, gg, bb, sample);
            dst = new BufferedImage(newModel, raster, dst.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
        }
        dst.createGraphics().drawImage(src, 0, 0, null);
        return dst;
    }

    public static void saveAnimatedGIF(OutputStream out, List<GifFrame> frames, int loopCount) throws Exception
    {
        ImageWriter iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif").next();

        ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
        iw.setOutput(ios);
        iw.prepareWriteSequence(null);

        int p = 0;
        for (GifFrame frame : frames)
        {
            ImageWriteParam iwp = iw.getDefaultWriteParam();
            IIOMetadata metadata = iw.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(frame.img), iwp);
            ImageUtil.configureGIFFrame(metadata, String.valueOf(frame.delay / 10L), p++, frame.disposalMethod, loopCount);
            IIOImage ii = new IIOImage(frame.img, null, metadata);
            iw.writeToSequence(ii, null);
        }

        iw.endWriteSequence();
        ios.close();
    }

    private static void configureGIFFrame(IIOMetadata meta, String delayTime, int imageIndex, String disposalMethod, int loopCount)
    {
        String metaFormat = meta.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

        if (!"javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0".equals(metaFormat))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unfamiliar gif metadata format: " + metaFormat);
        }

        Node root = meta.getAsTree(metaFormat);

        Node child = root.getFirstChild();
        while (child != null)
        {
            if ("GraphicControlExtension".equals(child.getNodeName()))
                break;
            child = child.getNextSibling();
        }

        IIOMetadataNode gce = (IIOMetadataNode) child;
        gce.setAttribute("userDelay", "FALSE");
        gce.setAttribute("delayTime", delayTime);
        gce.setAttribute("disposalMethod", disposalMethod);

        if (imageIndex == 0)
        {
            IIOMetadataNode aes = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtensions");
            IIOMetadataNode ae = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");
            ae.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
            ae.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
            byte[] uo = new byte[] { 0x1, (byte) (loopCount & 0xFF), (byte) ((loopCount >> 8) & 0xFF) };
            ae.setUserObject(uo);
            aes.appendChild(ae);
            root.appendChild(aes);
        }

        try
        {
            meta.setFromTree(metaFormat, root);
        }
        catch (IIOInvalidTreeException e)
        {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**TestGif.java:**

```
public class TestGif {

    private JFrame frame;
    private URL url = null;

    public ArrayList<BufferedImage> getFrames(URL gif) throws IOException{
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> frames = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        ImageReader ir = new GIFImageReader(new GIFImageReaderSpi());
        URLConnection urlconnection = gif.openConnection();
        ir.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(urlconnection.getInputStream()), false);
        for(int i = 0; i < ir.getNumImages(true); i++){
            ImageReadParam param = ir.getDefaultReadParam();
            frames.add(ir.read(i, param));
        }
        return frames;
    }

    public TestGif() throws FileNotFoundException {
        frame = new JFrame("teste");
        try {
            url = new URL("http://sadpanda.us/images/872436-4CD65DA.gif");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestGif.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        List<GifFrame> gifFrames = new ArrayList<GifFrame>();
        ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = null;
        try {
            images = getFrames(url);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(BufferedImage image: images)
        {
            int transparantColor = image.getRGB(0, 0); // purple
            BufferedImage gif = ImageUtil.convertRGBAToGIF(image, transparantColor);
            long delay = 100; // every frame takes 100ms
            String disposal = GifFrame.RESTORE_TO_BGCOLOR; // make transparent pixels not 'shine through'
            gifFrames.add(new GifFrame(gif, delay, disposal));
        }

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\test.gif");

        int loopCount = 0; // loop indefinitely
        try {
            ImageUtil.saveAnimatedGIF(outputStream , gifFrames, loopCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ImageIcon icon = null;
        try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\DEVELOPER\\Desktop\\test.gif").toURI().toURL());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        icon.setImageObserver(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    new TestGif();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Result:**

http://sadpanda.us/images/874900-EFU9R4J.gif

The solution is not so optimized since I have to create a temporary animated GIF file which removes the annoying colorful square behind the main image and later load it as a labeled animated icon in a Swing GUI.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer eee, it acctualy works!
But why this happens to this .gif ? its because his enconding right? it is a bad .gif ? maybe I can open on photoshop this .gif and save it  with another properties so I wont need this full code?
Or this is what I need to do with any .gif file? it will always appear that squares behind ? 
Thanks alot mate!

Answer (score 2):

you have got problem with determine locations for where is dark.gif place

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("dark.gif");
```

in this case is possible get Icon/ImageIcon from URL

```
URL url = new URL("http://sadpanda.us/images/872436-4CD65DA.gif");
```

for example

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestGif {

    private JFrame frame;
    private URL url = null;

    public TestGif() {
        frame = new JFrame("teste");
        try {
            url = new URL("http://sadpanda.us/images/872436-4CD65DA.gif");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestGif.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        icon.setImageObserver(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new TestGif();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but I downloaded the file, and I am using on my directory mate, I can see the file but with some weird problem
look here how its showed
http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/8365/problemys.png
and that green square its always changing color while the gif moves..

Comment: I tested your example and it stills there is the squares error :s
thanks in advance

Comment: To remove the annoying colorful rotating squares behind the image, check http://riven8192.blogspot.com/2010/02/image-java-animated-gifs.html It will convert images from RGBA into indexed color model.

Comment: @eee I think that this [Swing Guru could be right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9557695/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel I have tried the solution from your last comment but with only one image in one row. Sometimes, it removes the colored square from behind the image of http://sadpanda.us/images/872436-4CD65DA.gif; sometimes it doesn't. Even, it doesn't animate. The solution I put forward in my comment earlier will give an image without the annoying square http://sadpanda.us/images/874881-2SAKIHQ.gif as a labeled animated icon. http://sadpanda.us/images/874887-K52DN48.png

Comment: example of corrected animated gif in action: http://sadpanda.us/images/874900-EFU9R4J.gif

Comment: @eee please post that as an answer, I'll up_voting your effort :-)