# Shape drawing controlled by mouse

Tags: java, graphics, awt, paint, mouselistener

How can we draw the shapes in Java like we do in paint?

For example if I want to draw the rectangle this command will draw it:

```
g2.fill3DRect(mt, mf, 45, 45, true);
```

But how can I increase the or decrease the size of an object or shape during run-time using mouse like we did in paint?

Comment: Side note.  People typically recommend overriding `paint()` or `paintComponent()` & using that `Graphics` object to paint to.  Here are 2 examples ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10055672/418556), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10055306/418556)) that instead use a `BufferedImage`.  We can grab the graphics object direct from the image, in order to do 'custom painting'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [mouse listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) to get the position of the mouse after it has been pressed. i.e.

```
g2.fill3DRect(mt, mf, mouse.getX(), mouse.getY(), true);
```

But clear the screen by drawing a rectangle over the entire screen before each draw so that there's not a million rectangles at the same time. This is the most basic example of course. Look into double buffering and practice.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a shape object that holds the attributes of the shape.

Your Panel should maintain a List of shapes that it draws when it needs to. Also one shape can be attached to the mouse.

Then register a mouselistener to your panel that will:

- update your shape and redraw the panel if you move the mouse.
- creates a new shape when you mouseDown
- releases the shape when you mouseUp