# Java Container remove method not working correctly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

i hava added 1.TextArea  2.TextField
then i start adding JButton successively on container...,now by using JRadioButton i want to remove JButton from container using this code

```
i=0;
k=0;
while(!birdButton[i].isSelected()){
    i++;    
}   
System.out.println(i);
k=i+2;
list.removeElementAt(i);
listName.removeElementAt(i);
System.out.println(k);
c.getContentPane().remove(k);
```

but when i select the 1st radiobutton 1st JButton should be deleted because of k=i+2;
  instead of deleting this one it deletes the TextArea(1st one).
when i select the 3rd radiobutton then 1st JButton is deleted. can anyone let me know what  the problem is? and also `System.out.println(i);` `System.out.println(k);` is not printing any value....here is the code

```
public class RadioDemo implements ActionListener {

    String buttonName;
    JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    Enumeration enl;
    int result;
    ActionEvent e;
    JRadioButton birdButton[];
    int i, k;

    Vector<String> listName;
    Vector<JComponent> list;
    Container c;

    public RadioDemo(Vector<String> listName,Vector<JComponent> list,Container c) {

        birdButton=new JRadioButton[listName.size()];
        this.listName=listName;
        this.c=c;
        this.list=list;

        i = 0;
        for (String buttonName : listName){
               birdButton[i] = new JRadioButton(buttonName);
               birdButton[i].setActionCommand(buttonName);
               group.add(birdButton[i]);
               birdButton[i].addActionListener(this);
               radioPanel.add(birdButton[i]);
               i++;
         }

        birdButton[0].setSelected(true);
        radioPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout

        (radioPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                                    //birdButton.setBorder

        (BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, radioPanel, "Please choose", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);                
        show();
    }

    /** Listens to the radio buttons. */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public void show() {
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while (!birdButton[i].isSelected()) {
                i++;

            }
            System.out.println(i);
            k = i + 2;
            list.removeElementAt(i);
            listName.removeElementAt(i);
            System.out.println(k);
            c.getContentPane().remove(k);
            c.getContentPane().validate();

            // System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
            // c.getContentPane().rePaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How about, instead, you maintain a relation ship between the Radio button the button you want to remove, maybe something like a `HashMap`?

Comment: I need to see how you constructed the UI as well

Answer (score 6):

The `Container` returned by `getContentPane()` is, by default, the `contentPane` of a `JRootPane` managed by the [top-level container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), `JFrame`. Although, "as a convenience, the `add` method and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary," there's no *a priori* way to know about the frame's internal use of component indices.

[image]

Instead, add on your own `JComponent` to the frame and operate on it; `JPanel` is a common choice.

Addendum: Also consider an alternative layout such as `CardLayout`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Comment: @kleopatra: Absolutely correct; thank you for critical review; more above.

Comment: just reading :-) Cool edit, would love to give you a second upvote!