# How to change/edit a JPanel object at startup/init

Tags: java, swing, initialization, jpanel, jcomponent

I want to change a JPanel-object in an applet at startup/init. I can't figure out how to do this. I've made a simple example of my problem in which I clear the JPanel. It does not work when it is called by the init() method but it works when I press the button. What can I do to change the JPanel at startup/init?

```java
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TestStartUpApplet extends JApplet {

    JPanel panel;   

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Init");
        erasePanel();
    }

    private void erasePanel() {
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 117, 48);
    }

    public TestStartUpApplet() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel.setBounds(35, 36, 117, 48);
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
        btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                erasePanel();
            }
        });
        btnTest.setBounds(35, 108, 117, 25);
        getContentPane().add(btnTest);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should click the check mark next to the answer you found most useful in order to accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

question

1. no idea why do you want to clear empty [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) without any custom painting
2. what's wrong with `JPanel` with red `Background`
3. you clear [JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) before became visible on the screen
4. doesn't works correctly, because doesn't works anything

suggestions

- don't use [AbsoluteLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html), use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) instead
- `Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();` is usefull for [printing to the printer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html), or save [Graphics to the image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html), don't use this method for another reason
- read how [JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html) works
- maybe to use [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) in the case that you don't want to publish your GUI to the web browser
- maybe to read tutorial about [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: 1&2) As I wrote, this is just an example. I am writing an application where I have a method that draws an image on a JPanel object. This has to be shown when the applet starts. Problem is the same. It works when I press a button but I cannot get it to work 'on startup'.

3) I guess that is the problem, so where can I put my method erasePanel() just after the moment the applet is visible?

4) That's why I posted my problem here ;-)

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Paul Koning  start with 2D Graphics tutorial, [there are a few examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+paintcomponent), painting for JPanale in the JApplet or JFrame or JDialog is the same, to try to avoiding to use method paint(), use only paintComponent() for Swing JComponents

Comment: @PaulKoning your making assumptions about how the paint engine works which are fundamentally wrong.  Try calling something like invalidate &/or repaint in the applets run method, rather then trying to circumvent the paint process (which is what your erase method is trying to do)

Comment: Thanks, it's clear to me that I have to change the code, I made my own panel class and now it works.

Comment: @PaulKoning: That's the right choice; also consider this [hybrid approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11372932/230513) for flexibility and this discussion of [`contentPane()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769153/230513).

Answer (score 3):

Works just for me:

```
public class AppletPaintTest extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void init() {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                ImagePane pane = new ImagePane();
                pane.setBackground(Color.RED);
                pane.setOpaque(false); // Little trick

                add(pane);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
    }

    public class ImagePane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int x = insets.left;
            int y = insets.top;
            int width = getWidth() - 1 - (insets.left + insets.right);
            int height = getHeight() - 2 - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(x + 10, y + 10, width - 20, height - 20);

            g2d.dispose();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me making my own panel class.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you do any custom painting outside of the usually system calls to your `paint()` or `paintComponent()` methods, you must call `invalidate()` on any components you wish to repaint. So for your `erasePanel()` method, I would suggest setting some flag then calling `panel.invalidate()`. Then inside your panel's `paintComponent()` method, you can check the flag to see if you need to draw the introductory picture or just leave the panel blank.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed a by making my own panel class.

Comment: An upvote would be nice. ;-) You should have enough reputation now.

Comment: I don't understand how `invalidate()` would be useful in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that the problem was that my coding was just bad. I wanted to change a panel object by a method from another class and that's not the way to do it. I rewrote my code and made a panel class in which the painting is done using paintcomponent. I now use objects of this panel class and it shows the graphics I want at startup.

Thanks for the help!