# issue about Concept of JFrame, JLabel and ContentPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, contentpane

I just study window programming with awt.

I see through several codes but I can not get concepts of JFrame, JLabel and ContentPane.

I think JFrame only make outer Frame.
ContentPane is container that contain JLabel that has contents(text, button, radio etc...).

I don't know this is correct T.T

Why I ask this is I failed combine the contents.
I can not make TextField and InternalFrame at a time.

I want to know the concept.
I hope you take my question right.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/. Note that JFrame and JLabel are Swing components, and not AWT components.

Comment: @JBNizet `JComponent extends Component`

Comment: @JBNizet so Swing components technically _are_ AWT components.

Comment: Except you're not supposed to use Swing components in AWT applications, and vice-versa. Swing components happen to inherit from AWT component, but as you said, it's only a technical relationship. You're nitpicking: What we call AWT components are heavyweight components in the AWT package. What we call Swing components are lightweight component in the swing package.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak both Trabant and Porsche are cars, isn't it, sure Swing is based on, inherits and nesting of methods came from AWT

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769153/230513) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get clean view for AWT vs Swing. Here is a good explanation for [Swing or AWT: Which is right for you?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/grid/library/os-swingswt)

**JFame :** 
An extended version of java.awt.Frame that adds support for the JFC/Swing component architecture. See [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

**JLabel :** 
 Display component for your short text like `Name :` , `Phone Number :` etc., See [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

**Container :** 
 Container is a component that holds or wraps-up other components. It aids with grouping related components together in the GUI. Document of [Swing Containers](http://oreilly.com/catalog/jswing/chapter/ch08.pdf)