# How to generate the objects dynamically in Jeditorpane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

How to generate the objects dynamically in Jeditorpane?

For Eg: When i click on "Submit" button, it used to create editor pane objects dynamically such that i can get the values from editor pane or set the values to the editor pane using object name.

Thanks

Comment: Please post code showing what you have tried. This will also help to clarify your question (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

- create [JFrame as local variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), put there [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) in [JScrollpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)
- add [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to the [JButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [define HTMLEditorKit](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/UsejavaxswingtexthtmlHTMLEditorKittoparseHTML.htm)
- in [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to define `"objects dynamically in Jeditorpane"`

Comment: Also consider `JTextPane`, which has `insertComponent()`  and `insertIcon()` methods, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11744971/230513).