# Zoom box for area around mouse location on screen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, zooming

Is there any way to create a dynamic Zoom Box in Java which will include e. g. 20x20pix area around the cursor (but even when cursor will move beyond the Frame of app) and which will be shown for example in a small JPanel?

I'm asking in context of a Color Chooser program. The last functionality need to be implemented is just that Zoom Box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure there are a number of different ways that this could be achieved.

This basically uses a separate component, which acts as the "zoom box".  You supply it a component that you want to "zoom" on.  It adds a mouse listener so it can monitor mouse motion events and enter and exit events.

These are used to determine when the "popup" window should be shown, where the popup window should be shown and the area that should be "painted".

This uses the "component to be zoomed" `paint` method to paint a region to of it to a backing buffer, which is then scaled and painted to the "zoom box"...simple

I've not played around with the zoom factor, so there may still be some quirks, but you should get the basic idea...

While I've presented a image to act as the background, this should work on any component

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ZoomBoxWindow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ZoomBoxWindow();
  }

  public ZoomBoxWindow() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        TestPane pane = new TestPane();
        ZoomPane zoomPane = new ZoomPane(pane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public static class ZoomPane extends JPanel {

    protected static final int ZOOM_AREA = 40;

    private JComponent parent;
    private JWindow popup;

    private BufferedImage buffer;

    private float zoomLevel = 2f;

    public ZoomPane(JComponent parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
      popup = new JWindow();
      popup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      popup.add(this);
      popup.pack();
      MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
          Point p = e.getPoint();
          Point pos = e.getLocationOnScreen();
          updateBuffer(p);
          popup.setLocation(pos.x + 16, pos.y + 16);
          repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
          popup.setVisible(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
          popup.setVisible(false);
        }

      };

      parent.addMouseListener(ma);
      parent.addMouseMotionListener(ma);
    }

    protected void updateBuffer(Point p) {
      int width = Math.round(ZOOM_AREA);
      int height = Math.round(ZOOM_AREA);
      buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
      AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

      int xPos = (ZOOM_AREA / 2) - p.x;
      int yPos = (ZOOM_AREA / 2) - p.y;

      if (xPos > 0) {
        xPos = 0;
      }
      if (yPos > 0) {
        yPos = 0;
      }

      if ((xPos * -1) + ZOOM_AREA > parent.getWidth()) {
        xPos = (parent.getWidth() - ZOOM_AREA) * -1;
      }
      if ((yPos * -1) + ZOOM_AREA > parent.getHeight()) {
        yPos = (parent.getHeight()- ZOOM_AREA) * -1;
      }

      at.translate(xPos, yPos);
      g2d.setTransform(at);
      parent.paint(g2d);
      g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel), Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      if (buffer != null) {
        AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoomLevel, zoomLevel));
        g2d.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
      }
      g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
      g2d.dispose();
    }

  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public TestPane() {
      try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/image"));
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      if (img != null) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
        g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        g2d.dispose();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

**Updated with "screen" version**

This version will allow you to display a "zoom window" any where on the screen.

This has a minor issue in the fact that you need to hide the zoom window before you capture the screen, then re-show it.

I might be tempted to change the process so that when the `updateBuffer` method detected that the mouse position hadn't changed, it updated the buffer and showed the zoom window.  When the mouse position changes, it would hide the window again...but that's me ;)

[image]

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static zoomboxwindow.ZoomBoxWindow.ZoomPane.ZOOM_AREA;

public class GlobalZoomBox {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GlobalZoomBox();
  }

  public GlobalZoomBox() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Zoomer zoomer = new Zoomer();
        zoomer.setZoomWinodwVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class Zoomer extends JPanel {

    protected static final int ZOOM_AREA = 40;

    private JWindow popup;

    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Robot bot;

    private float zoomLevel = 2f;
    private Point lastPoint;
    private final Timer timer;

    public Zoomer() {
      popup = new JWindow();
      popup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      popup.add(this);
      popup.pack();
      try {
        bot = new Robot();
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      timer = new Timer(125, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          updateBuffer();
        }
      });
      timer.setCoalesce(true);
      timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    }

    public void setZoomWinodwVisible(boolean value) {

      if (value && !popup.isVisible()) {

        timer.start();
        popup.setVisible(true);

      } else {

        timer.stop();
        popup.setVisible(false);

      }

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel), Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel));
    }

    protected void updateBuffer() {
      if (bot != null) {
        PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point p = info.getLocation();
        if (lastPoint == null || !lastPoint.equals(p)) {
          int x = p.x - (ZOOM_AREA / 2);
          int y = p.y - (ZOOM_AREA / 2);
          popup.setLocation(p.x + 16, p.y + 16);
          popup.setVisible(false);
          buffer = bot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, ZOOM_AREA, ZOOM_AREA));
          popup.setVisible(true);
          lastPoint = p;
          repaint();
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      if (buffer != null) {
        AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoomLevel, zoomLevel));
        g2d.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
      }
      g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
      g2d.dispose();
    }

  }

}
```

**Updated with "tooltip" style popup**

The main problems with the second example is the fact that you need to hide the popup in order to grab a screen shoot.  This is done to prevent the popup from begin captured as well.  This makes the popup "flash" every time the mouse is moved.

You "could" get around this ensuring the popup is positioned out side the range of the capture, but as you increase the capture area, the popup will move further away from the cursor.

This would, of course, be a great solution for fixed position display (ie, you had a panel fixed on a `JFrame` instead of a floating box)

This is an additional update that uses a second timer to display the zoom box after the user has stopped moving the mouse.

[image]

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import static zoomboxwindow.ZoomBoxWindow.ZoomPane.ZOOM_AREA;

public class GlobalZoomBox {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GlobalZoomBox();
  }

  public GlobalZoomBox() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Zoomer zoomer = new Zoomer();
        zoomer.setZoomWinodwVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class Zoomer extends JPanel {

    protected static final int ZOOM_AREA = 80;

    private JWindow popup;

    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Robot bot;

    private float zoomLevel = 2f;
    private Point lastPoint;
    private final Timer timer;
    private final Timer popupTimer;

    public Zoomer() {
      popup = new JWindow();
      popup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      popup.add(this);
      popup.pack();
      try {
        bot = new Robot();
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      timer = new Timer(125, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          updateBuffer();
        }
      });
      timer.setCoalesce(true);
      timer.setInitialDelay(0);

      popupTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          if (lastPoint != null) {
            System.out.println("lastPoint = " + lastPoint);
            popup.setVisible(false);
            Point p = lastPoint;
            int x = p.x - (ZOOM_AREA / 2);
            int y = p.y - (ZOOM_AREA / 2);
            popup.setLocation(p.x + 16, p.y + 16);
            buffer = bot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, ZOOM_AREA, ZOOM_AREA));
            repaint();
            popup.setVisible(true);
          }
        }
      });
      popupTimer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public void setZoomWinodwVisible(boolean value) {

      if (value && !popup.isVisible()) {

        timer.start();
        popup.setVisible(true);

      } else {

        timer.stop();
        popup.setVisible(false);

      }

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel), Math.round(ZOOM_AREA * zoomLevel));
    }

    protected void updateBuffer() {
      if (bot != null) {
        PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point p = info.getLocation();
        if (lastPoint == null || !lastPoint.equals(p)) {
          lastPoint = p;
          popupTimer.stop();
          popup.setVisible(false);
        } else {
          if (!popup.isVisible()) {
            popupTimer.start();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
      if (buffer != null) {
        AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
        g2d.setTransform(AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(zoomLevel, zoomLevel));
        g2d.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.setTransform(at);
      }
      g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2d.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
      g2d.dispose();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Pretty cool idea with little box following a cursor but... shame it's only occurs in the parent component borders. Is it possible to extend or make independent box/tooltip existence from parent components?

Comment: As I said, it should be possible to pass it any component, so you, for example, pass it the content pane of the frame and it should be able see all the child components as well. Or are you looking for a solution that can be used on any part of the screen?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that can be used on whole screen.

Comment: I'll see what I am whip up ;)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to figure it out either :)

Comment: I've updated with a "screen" version

Comment: Excelent! Thank you very much. But why you use setVisible() toggle in updateBuffer() method? :P Without those statements it's working much more smoother. Repaint() do the trick :)

Comment: I found that I was capturing the zoom box when ever I did screen grab.  If you change the zoom area, you might find it grabs this box again...

Comment: Couldn't resist, added an additional example that works a little like a tooltip, in that it will wait till the mouse has stopped moving and then display the popup window ;)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Zoom On Mouse]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

class ZoomOnMouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        final Robot robot = new Robot();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int size = 256;
                final BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                        size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                final JLabel gui = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
                ActionListener zoomListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        PointerInfo pi = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                        Point p = pi.getLocation();
                        BufferedImage temp = robot.createScreenCapture(
                                new Rectangle(p.x-(size/4), p.y-(size/4), 
                                (size/2), (size/2)));
                        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
                        g.drawImage(temp, 0, 0, size, size, null);
                        g.dispose();
                        gui.repaint();
                    }
                };
                Timer t = new Timer(40, zoomListener);
                t.start();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);

                t.stop();
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```