# Java SWT: Show Zoombox around cursor

Tags: java, swing, swt

I need your help with my application.

I'm writing a program that displays big images in tiles, using the SWT MapWidget (http://mappanel.sourceforge.net/swt/).
The user has the ability to place markers on the map, when he pressed the mouse for a couple seconds. Additionally, I also need a little ZoomBox next to the cursor that shows the area around the cursor, so that the user has better precision when placing a marker. This ZoomBox is to be displayed while the user keeps the mouse pressed. Placing the markers ia already working fine.
I have problems with implementing the ZoomBox, specifically displaying it. I found a post that does just what I need ([Zoom box for area around mouse location on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen)). The problem is, this post is for Swing and not for SWT.

I have already built a SWT_AWT-Bridge, so I have the ZoomPanel already in my shell. What I need is the functionality of displaying it on top of the MapWidget, while the user keeps the mouse pressed.

I figured, I need to use a `StackLayout`, but I don't know how.

**EDIT**
To clarify, my question is, how can I display the composite containing my ZoomBox on top of my image, while the user keeps the mouse pressed?

Comment: ..does this have anything to do with Swing?  Also, what is your question?  (A requirement is not a question.)

Comment: @Andrew The connection to Swing is that the ZoomBox I'm using from the other post is in Swing and I'm using a SWT_AWT-Bridge to include it. I edited my post to clarify my question.

Comment: *"I edited my post to clarify my question."*  I see that did not extend to including a '?' at the end of it..