# Capture pixels behind window without hiding it

Tags: java, screenshot

How can I capture pixels behind my window, or take a screenshot without my window?

The only thing I can think of is hiding my window, taking a screenshot, then showing my window again. This is unacceptable.

I want to obtain the colors of pixels behind my window (as if my window isn't there), process them, then show the processed image inside my window.

Windows 7 Aero does it right here:

[image: Part of an Aero window showcasing the 'Glass' effect of the borders which blur what's beneath it]

It's also important that it's animated. When the application behind my window changes, I want my program to pick it up and show the changes. I don't care about framerate for now, even 1fps is fine, as long as I see the changes (like the blur in Aero does when you hold it over a video).

How can I emulate this behavior without ever hiding my window, which would cause flickering and other problems (like unable to drag the window) ?

I'm also versed in JNA if that's what it takes. (under Windows)

[EDIT] Made an elaborate mockup of what I'm trying to achieve (among other things):

[image: Youtube with a Java window in front of it, which zooms the video like a magnifying glass]

Comment: I doubt it's possible, unless you can somehow get a handle to the window behind it and get it to paint to your buffer some how. You should know that the os is optimised in such away that if a window is obscured in part or whole, then the obscured areas won't be painted. Depending on your needs, you might be able to make you window translucent

Comment: That's only true for opaque shapeless windows. If you make your window circular or change the transparency, then of course Windows decides to not optimize away those portions of the windows behinds yours. Transparent window is not an option because I need to process those pixels (like sharpening or magnifying or anything else that doesn't just map each pixel to itself)

Comment: How important is Java? When you're on Windows only, C# would be better suited for the task.

Comment: Java is the only language I speak, and I speak it quite fluently. On the other hand, C# is Greek to me.

Comment: Even with a translucent window, you're still talking about trying to get trying to unbake a cake. Consider having a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen/18158845#18158845)

Comment: I see. In the mean time I found this, and when I get home after work I'm going to dive into the source to see if I can port it to Java. http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/