# Create a swing gui to manipulate png pixel by pixel

Tags: java, swing, png, pixel

As i've declared in title of my question, I'm about to make a sort of editor of particular areas of a given png image to change colours pixel by pixel by clicking on it, maybe helping myself magnifying the area...

I'm mainly stuck because I don't know, ad I didn't find so far a solution to display a png which has a "grid" that divides every pixel.

I mean, a sort of thin line that like crosswords could "highlight" every pixel.

Pls point me in the right direction!

thanks!

Comment: Start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and also have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and 
[Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html)

Comment: I assume you mean, you want to generate a grid where each cell is, lets say, 5x5 pixels, and then fill that cell with the color of the pixel from the original image, for example?

Comment: mmm no, just pixel by pixel. I'm actually a retro-game developer (so I'm making graphics for old systems...) and resolution has to be lowered down. I need an editor that could let me change colour value of a single pixel. So I need a "grid" that could point out each one.

Comment: But, you want the image "zoomed", so a single pixel in the image will, for example, be 5x5 pixels in your view? Otherwise you'll just end up with a blank component (as each line of grid will be right next to each other), no?

Comment: yes surely i need zoomed zone, maybe the program could show the entire image with a selectable portion....and then the magnified part with famous grid solution by it's side ....well...for example did u know "yychr" program? pls take a look http://www.geocities.co.jp/Playtown-Denei/4503/yychr/yychr_j5.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: SpriteEditor]

Okay, so basically, what this is does is a very "simple" scaling process.  Each pixel in the image is represented by a "cell" which has a size.  Each cell is filled with the color of the pixel.  A simple grid is then overlaid on top.

You can use the slider to change the scaling (making the grid larger or smaller).

The example also makes use of the tool tip support to show the pixel color

This example doesn't providing editing though.  It would be a trival matter to add a `MouseListener` to the `EditorPane` and using the same algorithm as the `getToolTipText` method, find the pixel which needs to be updated.

My example was using a large sprite (177x345) and is intended to provide for a variable sized sprite.  Smaller or fixed sized sprites will provide better performance.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new SpriteEditorSpane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class SpriteEditorSpane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel sprite;
        private JSlider zoom;
        private EditorPane editorPane;

        public SpriteEditorSpane() throws IOException {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(new File("sprites/Doctor-01.png"));
            sprite = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(source));

            editorPane = new EditorPane();
            editorPane.setSource(source);

            zoom = new JSlider(2, 10);
            zoom.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    editorPane.setGridSize(zoom.getValue());
                }
            });
            zoom.setValue(2);
            zoom.setPaintTicks(true);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(sprite, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridheight = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(new JScrollPane(editorPane), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 0;
            add(zoom, gbc);

        }

    }

    public class EditorPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        private BufferedImage source;
        private BufferedImage gridBuffer;

        private int gridSize = 2;
        private Color gridColor;

        private Timer updateTimer;

        public EditorPane() {
            updateTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    doBufferUpdate();
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            updateTimer.setRepeats(false);
            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    updateBuffer();
                }
            });
            setGridColor(new Color(128, 128, 128, 128));
            setToolTipText("Sprite");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return source == null ? new Dimension(200, 200)
                    : new Dimension(source.getWidth() * gridSize, source.getHeight() * gridSize);
        }

        public void setGridColor(Color color) {
            if (color != gridColor) {
                this.gridColor = color;
                updateBuffer();
            }
        }

        public Color getGridColor() {
            return gridColor;
        }

        public void setSource(BufferedImage image) {
            if (image != source) {
                this.source = image;
                updateBuffer();
            }
        }

        public void setGridSize(int size) {
            if (size != gridSize) {
                this.gridSize = size;
                updateBuffer();
            }
        }

        public BufferedImage getSource() {
            return source;
        }

        public int getGridSize() {
            return gridSize;
        }

        @Override
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
            Point p = event.getPoint();
            int x = p.x / getGridSize();
            int y = p.y / getGridSize();

            BufferedImage source = getSource();
            String tip = null;
            if (x < source.getWidth() && y < source.getHeight()) {

                Color pixel = new Color(source.getRGB(x, y), true);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
                sb.append("<html><table><tr><td>");
                sb.append("R:").append(pixel.getRed());
                sb.append(" G:").append(pixel.getGreen());
                sb.append(" B:").append(pixel.getBlue());
                sb.append(" A:").append(pixel.getAlpha());
                String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", pixel.getRed(), pixel.getGreen(), pixel.getBlue(), pixel.getAlpha());
                sb.append("</td></tr><tr><td bgcolor=").append(hex);
                sb.append("width=20 height=20>&nbsp;</td></tr></table>");

                tip = sb.toString();

            }

            return tip;
        }

        @Override
        public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent event) {
            Point p = new Point(event.getPoint());
            p.x += 8;
            p.y += 8;
            return p;
        }

        protected void doBufferUpdate() {
            BufferedImage source = getSource();
            int gridSize = getGridSize();
            gridBuffer = null;
            if (source != null) {
                gridBuffer = new BufferedImage(source.getWidth() * gridSize, source.getHeight() * gridSize, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = gridBuffer.createGraphics();
                for (int row = 0; row < source.getHeight(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < source.getWidth(); col++) {
                        int xPos = col * gridSize;
                        int yPos = row * gridSize;
                        Color pixel = new Color(source.getRGB(col, row), true);
                        g2d.setColor(pixel);
                        g2d.fillRect(xPos, yPos, gridSize, gridSize);
                        g2d.setColor(getGridColor());
                        g2d.drawRect(xPos, yPos, gridSize, gridSize);
                    }
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            } else if (getWidth() > 0 && getHeight() > 0) {
                gridBuffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2d = gridBuffer.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(gridColor);
                for (int xPos = 0; xPos < getWidth(); xPos += gridSize) {
                    g2d.drawLine(xPos, 0, xPos, getHeight());
                }
                for (int yPos = 0; yPos < getHeight(); yPos += gridSize) {
                    g2d.drawLine(0, yPos, getWidth(), yPos);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void updateBuffer() {
            updateTimer.restart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (gridBuffer != null) {
                g2d.drawImage(gridBuffer, 0, 0, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            Container parent = getParent();
            return parent instanceof JViewport
                    && parent.getWidth() > getPreferredSize().width;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            Container parent = getParent();
            return parent instanceof JViewport
                    && parent.getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height;
        }

    }
}
```

The overall performance is pretty slow when generating the "grid", you might be able to use `byte[] bytes = ((DataBufferByte)gridBuffer.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData()` which will give you a `byte` array of the pixels, but in my testing, it didn't make that big a difference.

You might also like to have a look at [Zoom box for area around mouse location on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen/18158845#18158845)

Comment: Definetely a complete approach to study on. Well done and thanks a lot. Only one thing, at row 78 couldn't be just: editorPane = new EditorPane();?

Comment: Yes, I had planned a larger example (multiple sprites) but ran out of time