# How to know if the mouse is on a specific color with mouseEvent()

Tags: java, colors, mouseevent, mouselistener

Is there anyway of knowing if the mouse is on a color? For example, if the mouse touches black ( or any other color) it does something.

Thanks

Comment: The answer would depend a lot on what you are trying to do and what you already have available.  For example, if your doing a game, then you probably already have the scene rendered and could just inspect that last known location of the mouse.  If you're trying to do a color capture still mechanism across the whole screen, the process would be much more difficult

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen/18158845#18158845) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344309/create-a-swing-gui-to-manipulate-png-pixel-by-pixel/34346818#34346818)

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, i am doing a game "Scary Maze" type. What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: The second example might give you an idea.  Depending on how the rendering process works, if you have the "frame" pre-rendered to a backing buffer (like a `BufferedImage`), it's would be a trivial matter to look up the color of the pixel in the image, based on the last known location of the mouse (which you'd capture before the update cycle)

Comment: Assuming you're using Swing of course, you could take a look at [How to Write a Mouse Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [How to Write a Mouse-Motion Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think I understand what I have to do, I'll search a bit more and I'll give it a shot, thank you.