# Java- Zooming around mousePoint and Selection afterwards

Tags: java, select, zooming

I want to add the zooming function around the MOUSE, but I want to keep the unscaled values because I need to used it to selected item afterwards. The select item works perfectly before the zooming around the mousePoint:

```
    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
    if (mainWindow != null) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        int zoomX = (int)(intialDimension.width * mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());
        int zoomY = (int)(intialDimension.height* mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        g2d.scale(mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom(), mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());
    
        MainDrawer mainDrawer = new MainDrawer(mainWindow.controller, this.chaletDrawer, new   Dimension(zoomX, zoomY));
        mainDrawer.draw(g2d);
        
        g2d.dispose();

    }
}
```

MoussePressed :

```
    Point mousePoint = evt.getPoint(); double scaleZoom = controller.getScaleZoom();
    // Convert the mouse coordinates back to the unscaled (original) coordinates
    // 100 is the initial point of the drawing
    // 4 is the scale of the drawing
    int unscaledX = (int) ((mousePoint.x / scaleZoom - 100) / 4);
    int unscaledY = (int) ((mousePoint.y / scaleZoom - 100) / 4);

    System.out.println("Unscaled Mouse Point: (" + unscaledX + ", " + unscaledY + ")");

    this.controller.switchSelectionStatusAccessoire(unscaledX, unscaledY, viewType);
    this.drawingPanel.repaint();`
```

MouseWheel :

```
double amount = Math.pow(1.1, evt.getScrollAmount());       `

if (evt.getWheelRotation() > 0) {             
    controller.setScaleZoom(oldzoom * amount);         
} else {             
    controller.setScaleZoom(oldzoom / amount);         
}            
this.drawingPanel.repaint();
```

I can easily adapt the code to zoom aroud the mousePoint using AffineTransform. The problem is, afterward when I select it's not selecting at the good place and because I call the repaint in the MousePressed it will redraw the entire drawing at the initial position.

```
@Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {    
        if (mainWindow != null) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        int zoomX = (int) (intialDimension.width * mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());
        int zoomY = (int) (intialDimension.height * mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Point mousePosition = getMousePosition();
        AffineTransform at = g2d.getTransform();
        if (mousePosition != null) {
            at.translate(mousePosition.getX(), mousePosition.getY());
        }
        at.scale(mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom(), mainWindow.controller.getScaleZoom());
        if (mousePosition != null) {

            at.translate(-mousePosition.getX(), -mousePosition.getY());
        }
        g2d.setTransform(at);

        revalidate();
        
        MainDrawer mainDrawer = new MainDrawer(mainWindow.controller, this.chaletDrawer, new Dimension(zoomX, zoomY));
        mainDrawer.draw(g2d);


        g2d.dispose();

    }
}`
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen/18158845#18158845); You could also make use of the `JLayer` APIs [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174997/how-to-add-mouselistener-to-item-on-java-swing-canvas/21175125#21175125)

Comment: I can't used pop Up I have to directly zoom in the drawing

Comment: Maybe, it will give you some ideas