# Adding icon on JTabbedpane tab

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am having a JTabbedPane on my Form. The problem is I want to display icons to the Tabs of my TabbedPane.

How can i do that?

Comment: Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055336/jtabbedpane-show-task-progress-in-a-tab/10055387#10055387) of a rotating icon on a `JTabbedPane`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `setIconAt` method of the `JTabbedPane`:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setIconAt(int, javax.swing.Icon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setIconAt%28int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29)

Answer (score 3):

Please read the java tutorials first, they are really informative:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html