# change the size of a tabbedPane´s TAB & add an icon into it

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

Regards.

I need to change the size of the "tab" of a tabbedpane  but i don´t know how, hope someone can help me.

```
    JButton l = new JButton("first tab");
    l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));


    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(1, l);
    tabbedPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

in the previous code i have tried to add a button as a tab but no works.

[tab example of my program 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTPgs.png)

Comment: This question has already been answered here
-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360964/adding-icon-on-jtabbedpane-tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding icon on JTabbedpane tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360964/adding-icon-on-jtabbedpane-tab)

Comment: i need to resize the tab size